# Have clarification about syntax of arrow function while iterating data in react's render function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I am just iterating some data from API using arrow function inside render function of react like this.

```
render() {
  const postItem = this.props.posts.map((post, index) => {
    <div key={post.id}>
      <p>{index}</p>
      <h4>{post.title}</h4>
      <p>{post.body}</p>
    </div>
  })
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Posts</p>
      {postItem}
    </div>
  )
}
```

then it throws error

## (Please look curly braces after arrow, if put "(" inplace of curly braces "{" then every things goes fine)

like "Expected an assignment or function call instead saw an expression", but if I put ( after => then everythings goes fine.

But my doubt is that correct syntax of an arrow is like this () => {}.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

The pair of braces forms a block, containing a list of statements. You need to use a return statement explicitly to make the function return something.
If you omit the braces, the arrow function has a concise body, which consists solely of a single expression whose result will implicitly become the return value of the function.

How it helps!!!

Comment: Thanks a lot. It really cleared my doubt.

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning anything. When using an arrow function you have two options here.

#### 1. Concise body

```
render() {
  const postItem = this.props.posts.map((post, index) => {
    return (
      <div key={post.id}>
        <p>{index}</p>
        <h4>{post.title}</h4>
        <p>{post.body}</p>
      </div>
    )
  })
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Posts</p>
      {postItem}
    </div>
  )
}
```

---

#### 2. Block body

```
render() {
  const postItem = this.props.posts.map((post, index) => {
    return (
      <div key={post.id}>
        <p>{index}</p>
        <h4>{post.title}</h4>
        <p>{post.body}</p>
      </div>
    )
  })
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Posts</p>
      {postItem}
    </div>
  )
}
```

When you write `() => {}` you are not returning anything from your expression. This is the so called block body notation, it requires a **explicit** return statement. When you write `() => ()` you are using a so called concise body, it will work since the return is **implicit**. You can read more here: [Arrow functions: Function body (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It really cleared my doubt.

Answer (score 1):

In a traditional function declaration, a return statement is needed.

```
function Foo(bar) {
  // do something..
  return bar
}
```

When using arrow syntax a return statement is also needed:

```
const Foo = (bar) => {
  // do something..
  return bar
}
```

These 2 functions are identical.

Let's consider this example:

```
const adder = (a, b) => {
  return a + b
}
```

This function can be reduced down to this:

```
const adder = (a, b) => a + b
```

As you can see no `{}` no `return` needed.
Do consider though, if, through (for example) debugging, you need to add a `console.log` to the adder function:

```
const adder = (a, b) =>
  console.log(a) 
  a + b
```

this will break the function (it will return the console.log ), so an amendment would be needed to revert to previous function structure.

```
const adder = (a, b) => {
  console.log(a)
  return a + b
}
```

In answer to the `'('` bracket part of your question, let's consider this function, whose purpose it is to return an object `{}`:

```
const Foo = bar => {
  return {
    objectProperty: bar
  }
}
```

Now we want to reduce this down, as per the previous example.

```
const Foo = bar => { objectProperty: bar }
```

But this will now break. Because although 'we' want the `{}` to be our object definition, they are read by the compiler as the function statement `{}`
By wrapping the object in `()` prevents this action.

```
const Foo = bar => ({ objectProperty: bar })
```

This will now correctly return the object.